# Can Apache Tomcat handle HTTP POST requests > 2 GB?

Tags: tomcat

I could not find any positive or negative answer to this question in the official Tomcat documentation.

Comment: What type of request it is. Is it a File Upload or the actual POST body is of 2 GB

Comment: The actual case that led to this question was a file upload where the limit seemed to be 2 GB. But in theory, when accessing the input streams, it should not matter how the body content is structured. So this question is about the more common case.

Comment: Oh it is. If you do File upload, it becomes Multipart request and Server can stream the data more efficiently as most of it is binary. For regular POST which is not File Upload (Assume 2GB of JSON text), you need that much amount of memory on both Client and Server side to handle that request. File Uploads work more efficiently by using streaming behavior. I have done a project where File Upload was more than 8 GB (Imagine Virtual Machine uploads),

Comment: But it is not recommended as it is not that efficient. Most of the time You should try to avoid File Upload more than 1 GB and provide a way to upload bigger file Like FTP/SFTP or Dropbox like protocol.

Comment: I know this. But the question is neither about processing the uploaded data nor if it is a good idea to upload large amounts of data via HTTP. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**

From the [Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html) that you surely already read :

> maxPostSize
>   The maximum size in bytes of the POST which will be handled by the container FORM URL parameter parsing. **The limit can be disabled by setting this attribute to a value less than or equal to 0**. If not specified, this attribute is set to 2097152 (2 megabytes).

It does mean that you can specify a limit for your application, and that limit can be ***unlimited***. In theory, tomcat does not have a limit as long as you have the necessary hardware.

Comment: The `maxPostSize` seems not to be in effect in a Tomcat 8.0 or 8.5 standard installation. According to the non-blocking I/O byte counter example, uploads with less than 2 GB seem to be no problem at all. Meanwhile I had several machines (physical, dockerized and virtualized) where I could upload files with 3.0 GiB in size, but at least some failed with slightly larger payloads. This is surprising since I would expect that streaming I/O should be capable of handling almost arbitrary size if it could handle > 2 GiB. However, I'll try if setting `maxPostSize` has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Tests turned out that Apache Tomcat can handle requests of arbitrary size at least since version 6.0.

There's no need to modify the configuration of the standard installation to be able to handle large synchronous request.

However, for asynchronous requests (non-blocking I/O) there's a default timeout of 30 seconds which, according to the network bandwidth, limits the amount of data that can be uploaded with a single request. This limit can be modified by setting the `asyncTimeout` connector property to an appropriate value.

Since Tomcat 8.0 with Servlet API 3.1 there's also the method [getContentLengthLong()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/index.html?javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) for determining content lengths > 2GB of servlet requests directly. In previous versions the `Content-Length` HTTP header had to be parsed explicitly in such cases.